# Not showing sponsor username, Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel, cookies

I'm making a multilevel system and we use the referral link, but the sponsor username is not appearing in the html of the registration page and to access it is necessary to log out of the current session.

My Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddReferrerToUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) 
        {
                $table->integer('referrer_id')->unsigned()->default(1)->after('id');
                $table->foreign('referrer_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table)
         {
                $table->dropForeign(['referrer_id']);
                $table->dropColumn( 'referrer_id' );
        });
    }
}
```

My Controller: refController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class RefController extends Controller
{
    public function index( $username )
     {
    $user = User::where( 'username', $username )->first();

    return ( is_null( $user ) )
        ? redirect( '/' )
        : redirect( '/register' )->withCookie( cookie()->forever( 'referrer_id', $user->id ) );
     }
}
```

My Routes:

```
Route::get('/user', function () {
    return redirect('/');
});

Route::get('/user/{username}', 'RefController@index' );
```

My Html:

```
    <?php if (isset($referrer_id->id)) { ?>

        <p class="login-box-msg" style="margin-top: 20px; margin-bottom: 30px; color: #373737;">You have been nominated for:<br><b>{{$referrer_id->name. ' - '. $referrer_id->email}}</b></p>

    <?php } ?>
```

My "referrer_id" structure is inside the "users" table.

Comment: can you get $referrer_id->id in your html code. ?

Comment: no, nothing just happens

Comment: ok so try this below code.

Comment: after using the sponsor link eg myexample.com/user/sponsor the registration page opens normally but wanted to show the sponsor name or username inside the page

Comment: so please select answer.

Comment: can you share screen shot of your tables.

Comment: I didn't understand the question, but all the necessary files are just these

Comment: please give me your html file name..

Comment: views/Auth/register.blade.php